# How to restore a saved model with LSTM layers in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I was following a [tutorial](https://chunml.github.io/ChunML.github.io/project/Creating-Text-Generator-Using-Recurrent-Neural-Network/) to generate English text using LSTMs and using Shakespeare's works as a training file. This is the model I am using with reference to that-

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(HIDDEN_DIM, input_shape=(None, VOCAB_SIZE), return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
for i in range(LAYER_NUM - 1):
    model.add(LSTM(HIDDEN_DIM, return_sequences=True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(VOCAB_SIZE)))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="rmsprop")
```

After 30 epochs of training, I save the model using `model.save('model.h5')`. At this point, the model has learned the basic format and has learned a few words. However, when I try to load the model in a new program using `load_model('model.h5')` and try to generate some text, it ends up predicting completely random letters and symbols. This led me to think that the model weights are not being restored properly, since I encountered the same problem while storing only the model weights. So is there any alternative for storing and restoring trained models with LSTM layers?

For reference, in order to generate the text, the function randomly generates a character and feeds it into the model to predict the next character. This is the function-

```
def generate_text(model, length):
    ix = [np.random.randint(VOCAB_SIZE)]
    y_char = [ix_to_char[ix[-1]]]
    X = np.zeros((1, length, VOCAB_SIZE))
    for i in range(length):
        X[0, i, :][ix[-1]] = 1
        print(ix_to_char[ix[-1]], end="")
        ix = np.argmax(model.predict(X[:, :i+1, :])[0], 1)
        y_char.append(ix_to_char[ix[-1]])
    return ('').join(y_char)
```

**EDIT**

The snippet of code for training-

```
for nbepoch in range(1, 11):
    print('Epoch ', nbepoch)
    model.fit(X, y, batch_size=64, verbose=1, epochs=1)
    if nbepoch % 10 == 0:
        model.model.save('checkpoint_{}_epoch_{}.h5'.format(512, nbepoch))
    generate_text(model, 50)
    print('\n\n\n')
```

Where generate_text() is just a function to predict a new character, starting from a randomly generated character. After every 10 epochs of training, the entire model is saved as a .h5 file.

The code for loading the model-

```
print('Loading Model')

model = load_model('checkpoint_512_epoch_10.h5')

print('Model loaded')

generate_text(model, 400)
```

As far as predictions go, the text generation is normally structured while training and the model learns some words. However, when the saved model is loaded, the text generation is completely random, as if the weights were randomly reinitialized.

Comment: Are you using model checkpoint to save the best iteration of the model? Additionally what you can use is save best model checkpoint using Keras callback and save model architecture using `to_json()` method. Then try to load model using json and load_weights method. You can find exact method name and callback details in Keras documentation.

Comment: @adityathakkar I am not using ModelCheckpoint to save the best iteration, but instead I am using the save_model() function every 10 epochs to save the entire model itself after a set number of epochs. I will try using the callback and let you know.

Comment: May I have a look at the (complete) code where u loaded your model weights?

Comment: @KrishnaChoudhary I added the snippets where I saved and loaded the models

Comment: @aadinaik You need to call `model.compile` . This can be done either before or after the `model.load_weights` call but must be after the model architecture is specified and before the `model.predict` call.

Comment: @KrishnaChoudhary I think calling load_model takes care of the `model.compile` process. According to the [docs](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-save-a-keras-model) - `You can then use keras.models.load_model(filepath) to reinstantiate your model. load_model will also take care of compiling the model using the saved training configuration (unless the model was never compiled in the first place).`

Comment: I managed to find a solution. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing a bit of digging, I finally found out that the way I was creating the dictionary mapping between characters and one-hot vectors was the issue. I was using the `char = list(set(data))` function to get a list of all the characters in the file, and then assign the index of the character as that character's 'code number'. However, apparently the `list(set(data))` function does not always output the same list, instead the order is randomized for each 'session' of python. So my dictionary mapping used to change between saving and loading the model, since that occurred in different scripts. Using `char = sorted(list(set(data)))` works to eliminate this problem.